# Ext.Msg.confirm callback is not creating a closure

Tags: extjs, callback, sencha-touch, closures, sencha-touch-2

Example:

```
disclose: function (list, record, node, index, event) {
    Ext.Msg.confirm('Delete Requirement', 'Are you sure?', function (id, value) {
        if (id === 'yes') {
            console.log('confirmed');

            // no access to list, record, node, ... here, why?
        }
    }, this);

    event.stopEvent();
}
```

How do I get access to the list and record variables inside the confirm message handler?

Comment: You _do_ have access to `list` and `record` there.  What are you seeing that make it look like you don't?

Comment: What does console.log(list); return then ?

Comment: Are you sure the event you're binding to 'disclose' actually provides (list, record) etc as params?

Comment: Sure, disclose does include list, record, etc. params. But inside callback they are undefined and Web Inspector doesn't show them in the local scope.

Comment: @Vitaly Weird.  Take a look at [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JohnnyHK/BSkZx/) which seems to be the same as what you're doing yet the callback can access `list`, `record`, etc. just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
disclose: function (list, record, node, index, event) {
    var l = list, r = record, n = node, i = index, e = event;
    Ext.Msg.confirm('Delete Requirement', 'Are you sure?', function (id, value) {
            if (id === 'yes') {
            console.log('confirmed', l, r, n, i, e);
        }
    }, this);

    event.stopEvent();
}
```

Comment: That works! I wonder why, though? Why wouldn't the closure see the parent function parameters but will see it's local variables? Aren't these essentially the same?

Comment: I'm not sure but i think it's bacause function's variables are actually `arguments[0]..arguments[n]`. So inside nested callback `arguments` are already different.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution:

```
disclose: function (list, record, node, index, event) {
    (new Ext.MessageBox).show({
         title: 'Delete Requirement',
         message: 'Are you sure?',
         list: list,
         record: record,
         buttons: Ext.MessageBox.YESNO,
         promptConfig: false,
         fn: function (id, value, opt) {
             if (id === 'yes') {
                 opt.record.destroy();
             }
         }
    });

    event.stopEvent();
}
```